# Meteor Package export sometimes missing

Tags: meteor

I have a package https://github.com/chicagogrooves/meteor-package-kitchen, which, in file `client/packageModel.js` defines a global:

```
 packageModel = {...}
```

And in `package.js`, we do an `api.use` of that file, followed by

```
 api.export("packageModel")
```

The problem is that the variable `packageModel` does not appear to be exported correctly. It is not present in the global scope on the client, despite appearing under the key `Package["deanius:package-kitchen"].packageModel`

To reproduce this, create any old Meteor app, do

```
 meteor add deanius:package-kitchen
```

and you will see the same problem, I suspect. This is Meteor 1.1.0.2. I have lost a ton of time on this - I feel like there is some kind of Meteor bug exhibited here - please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be the `debugOnly: true` on line 6 in your `package.js` file. If it's removed, the exported variable is visible. Of course, that doesn't solve your problem, since I'm assuming you want the package to be debug only.

Exported variables don't seem to work for `debugOnly` packages. Just to be sure, I tried another debug-only package(`msavin:mongol`) and it's exported variable(`Mongol`) is not directly visible either.

I think you'll have to file a bug report with the meteor people.

Comment: I guess that could be to keep you from writing production code that depends on it. Thanks for that answer, @prabu!